# ethereum.enable deprecated

Tags: solidity, metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp, console

Hello I was trying to follow this video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYwYe-Gv_XI&list=PLO5VPQH6OWdVQwpQfw9rZ67O6Pjfo6q-p&index=51&ab_channel=SmartContractProgrammer

where starting from the timestamp 11:06 he is using ethereum.enable in the browser console which is deprecated now .... Please tell me what is its replacement and how to use it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })` instead. In the video around timestamp 12:05, he used `ethereum.request({method: "personal_sign", params: [account, hash]})`.

According to Metamask docs:

> Use `request` to submit RPC requests to Ethereum via MetaMask. It returns a `Promise` that resolves to the result of the RPC method call.

> The `params` and return value will vary by RPC method. In practice, if a method has any `params`, they are almost always of type `Array<any>`.

> If the request fails for any reason, the Promise will reject with an Ethereum RPC Error.

See: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#legacy-methods

Comment: Even using that is giving me "pending" promise ... no matter what i write, the promise is "pending"

Comment: If you want to resolve the promise, you either need to use the "await" keyword or "Promise.prototype.then()".

Comment: I did but nothing happened after that.....  :(